# Effect on Force as Mass Doubles

Tags: forces

> A fireman is holding a hosepipe so that water leaves the pipe horizontally. The hose-pipe has a constant cross-sectional area. The magnitude of the force that the fireman exerts to hold the hosepipe stationary is $F$. The volume of water delivered by the hose per second doubles; the force that the fireman must exert now is...

As the density of the water remains constant, and density is $\frac{mass}{volume}$, as the volume doubles, the mass per second must double.

$F = ma$, where $a$ is constant and $m$ has doubled. Therefore, $F$ must have doubled.

However, the correct answer is $4F$. Can someone please point out the flaw in my conceptual understanding?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the volume doubled mass and velocity both get doubled,

The force is given by change in momentum, F=(mv-mu)/t

since the both mass and velocity get doubled the force becomes four times as initial stage!

Comment: Why does velocity double? It doesn't have to double, does it?

Comment: When volume get doubled, only way it can happen is doubling the velocity since the cross section area remains constant.  Think about water tap, when you open it full water comes faster therefore volume as well.